# How can I set sysdate in H2? (for testing)

Tags: java, sql, spring, integration-testing, h2

I use H2 for testing and I want to set `sysdate`.

I tried to create an alias for `sysdate` to my own implementation, but then I couldn't use it with arithmetic like `sysdate - ?`. There was exception: `Unknown data type: "?"`

I tried to replace `sysdate` string to smth like `timestamp '2018-01-01 11:11:11.123'` or `parsedatetime('2018-01-01 11:11:11.123', 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS')` in runtime. There was same exception, like in previous attempt.

Yes, I can add `cast(? as number)` to all my sql, but it isn't a good solution for me.

Do you have any idea, how can I do this?

ps: I also use Spring. Maybe it will help

Comment: Is it possible to move the date-handling logic out of the database and into Java?  That way the SQL gets simpler, the testing gets easier and you're less likely to run into error messages from H2.

Comment: Maybe you could create a function `SYSDATE()` that returns a date?

Answer (score 1):

If you use two databases at once, you should avoid usage of vendor-specific syntax.

You can use SQL Standard-compliant

`LOCALTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30' MINUTE`

in recent versions of Oracle and H2.

I already had this problem and that was the solution it worked.